# how to keep track of where I spend my time?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation

Is there any way in Ubuntu (11.04 to be exact) to keep track of how much time I spend on different web sites and in different applications?

I think this might help me be more productive.

I usually have many applications open at the same time, but only one of them is visible. The same with tabs in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I know [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com/) does this. I came across [this blogpost detailing how to install RescueTime in Ubuntu 11.04](http://my-metrics.blogspot.nl/2011/05/how-to-install-rescuetime-on-ubuntu.html):